# Django - Generate a pdf with html block text

Tags: django, python-2.7, pdf-generation, rendering, html-generation

I'm working on a project with Django (1.12) and python(2.7). I have a function which returns me in a string the content of an html page. I need to create the html page with this string, and after to transform it to pdf (already have the function), but WITHOUT leaving my actual page. I search since this morning on the internet but i don't find something like my case. 
Does anybody knows if it's possible ? and if yes, how?

Thanks,
@Nikotine

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Finally I choose an other method, seem's not to be possible like this (sorry it's forbidden for me to show my code).